# Codigo demora a executar, aponta erro mas depois apresenta o resultado

Tags: c, desempenho, otimização

Código no net beans executa, porém demora a mostrar o resultado. Aparece erro no console do netBeans, porem se eu deixar o programa rodando depois de um tempo ele mostra o resultado:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int res = 0, contador = 0;

    for (int num = 20; ; num++) {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            if (num % i == 0) {
                contador++;
            }
        }
        if (contador == 20) {
           res = num;
           break;
        }
        contador = 0;
    }

    printf("%d\n", res);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Ao rodar o programa aparece isso (erro no console do netBeans): 
[image: imagem]
Porém se eu deixar o programa executando por algum tempo (+- 40, 50 segundos) ele mostra o resultado mesmo dando erro: 
[image: ![funcionando]
O que eu devo fazer para otimizar / resolver esse problema?
PS: O resultado está certo, foi conferido nas respostas do projeto!!!

Comment: Note que você faz o teste if (contador == 20) { após um loop que pode incrementar a variável contador. Pode ser que dentro do loop o incremento da variável contador possa ultrapassar 20. Creio que o teste if (contador >= 20) { seja mais seguro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este algoritmo encontra o menor múltiplo comum dos primeiros n números naturais.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
    int n = 20;
    int res = 1;
    int prev;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        prev = res;
        while (res % i > 0) {
            res += prev;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", res);

    return (EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```